# Importing from CSV file, is crashing mysql server

Tags: mysql, import, csv

I am facing a problem with importing large data into single mysql table.
Basically I assume it is happening because limited machine resources but,
I am having troubles to proof it.

this is my CSV file information:

```
root@my:~# tail -n 1 /tmp/keys.csv 
ffff7771-e330-9d8e-6783-daf8a75fe4ef,7
root@my:~# wc -l /tmp/keys.csv 
162281544 /tmp/keys.csv
```

So basically I have 162,281,544 lines of

```
ffff7771-e330-9d8e-6783-daf8a75fe4ef,7
```

in my CSV and its file size is **6G**

I need to import this table on a daily basis and to use it only for SELECT information by the KEY eg:

```
SELECT uuid_tags_codes FROM keys WHERE uuid = 'ffff7771-e330-9d8e-6783-daf8a75fe4ef';
```

I choose MyISAM as my table engine because I read that it should be better from selecting information.

```
CREATE TABLE `keys` (
  `uuid` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `uuid_tags_codes` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`uuid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

After all this Information and I really hope it is clarifying all my technical stuff, If you think I missed something I will be happy to provide more details as you wish.

The problem is when I am using load data in file command as below:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/keys.csv'
INTO TABLE key
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(uuid,uuid_tags_codes);
```

After I am executing this command it mysql is running but it is unresponding and I have to delete the table from filesystem and restart it,
Also I think the system have no enough data storage **10G free** space in total before importing the file.
But this is OK I always can Improve the server machine, by extending the SSD size.

Here are my questions:

1. In case I extend my SSD drive should this process be OK, is mysql single table should be able to handle 6-8G data of 2 cols?
2. Is Mysql is the right solution to my case, or should I use different DB server for the pulling this info?
3. In case using mysql is ok, is my table definition is ok for the data I am storing in it? and what type of indexing should I use?

Comment: Because the table is bigger than can be cached; your _reads_ will each take about one disk hit.  Slow.  (UUIDs suck in this respect.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's do some calculation:

```
uuid: 36 bytes (Add 1 because it is varchar) ==> 37
uuid_tags_codes: 4 bytes
When indexed, full length of uuid field: 100 bytes

(37+4+100)bytes * 162,281,544 rows = 21.3 G
```

So, 21G without adding the overhead! Therefore, your first problem is the space.

To answer your questions:

1. It is more than 6-8G. To ba safe you need ~30G. Single MyISAM table can handle that. I don't recommend it though. MyISAM is not as safe as InnoDB for example.
2. MySQL is not wrong solution, but I think there are better solution. Since it is kind of look up table, key-value store would do better job. For example, memcache, Redis.
3. You can improve the structure by making `uuid char(36)`. In fact, [this article](http://mysqlserverteam.com/storing-uuid-values-in-mysql-tables/) has even more efficient solution. Also, use the smallest integer type that fits your maximum value of `uuid_tags_codes`
4. You may want to load the data first to the table without its indexes, then create the required index.

HTH

Comment: Thank you for you great answer, are memcache and redis storing data on disk, in other words will rhey be a solution to my case in such wheight of data?

Comment: memcache doesn't keep data on disk. Redis on the other hand can store the data on disk

Comment: Thank you for you help and answer I will consider migrating to redis

Answer (score 1):

- Sort the data by uuid before loading it -- this will speed up the load and shrink the disk space some (because of less fragmentation)
- Use InnoDB -- this will speed up the `SELECTs`.
- Pack the uuids into `BINARY(16)` -- this will shrink the disk space by perhaps a factor of 2.
- If `uuid_tags_codes` is just tiny numbers, use `TINYINT UNSIGNED` -- 1 byte instead of 4.  (Range: 0..255).  Or `SMALLINT UNSIGNED` (2 bytes; 0..64K)
- [*Stored routines for converting to/from `BINARY(16)`*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/uuid#code_to_do_it)

Comment: thank you very much for your tips, currently I migrated to redis but it looks like it will cost, I have to have 16GB ram machine which is quite expensive, I guess your answer will cut some of the resources in mysql, I will try to do it with mysql and see the results, It may save me some disk space and ram :)